# The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. when using facebook graph api

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

i'm developing an asp.net application. It's giving error. Any suggestions?

here is a portion of code behind:

```
    // Authenticated, created session and API object
    _connectSession = new ConnectSession(ApplicationKey, SecretKey);

    if (!_connectSession.IsConnected())
    {
        // Not authenticated, proceed as usual.

    }
    else
    {
        // Authenticated, create API instance
        _facebookAPI = new Api(_connectSession);

        // Load user
        user user = _facebookAPI.Users.GetInfo();
```

Here are details of the error:

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable host 69.63.176.141:80

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

thanks,
Gurbax Singh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what the error is telling you is that the API couldn't connect to the Facebook API server at the specified IP address.

That IP for the Facebook API doesn't seem to be in use.  Make sure you are using the latest versions of any Facebook API and that you look up the API server by hostname api.facebook.com

Currently I have it resolving to 69.63.181.46

More information available @ http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=50797